# Couch DB - Passing input parameters to view

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am moving from SQL to Couch DB from my web application, my very first application.

While i can not say why I do not like SQL queries, not sure that i don not, the idea of making CURL requests to access my database sound must better than using PHPs PDO .

I have spent a little over a day and a half trying to acquaint myself with the couch DB HTTP API. I can not claim I have throughly read the API , but who thoroughly reads an API before beginning  to code. So  my, possibly silly, question is - `how do I pass an variable other than doc to a map function while making a http request to the view.` The API clearly says that a map function only takes a single parameter which is "doc", in which case the function below itself is wrong but I can't find any section in the API that lets me query a database using end-user provided input.

my map function is

```
function(doc, pid2){

      if (doc.pid === pid2)
    {
        emit(doc._id, doc) ;

    }
}
```

pid2 is a number that will be provided by a front end user.

```
    <?php
    $pid2 = file_get_contents(facebook graphi api call_returns a Profile ID) ;
    $user_exists = HTTP request to couch DB view to return 
in JSON format the list of JSON documents with pid = $pid2
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let your view emit the documents with `doc.pid` as the key

```
function(doc) { 
    emit(doc.pid, doc);
}
```

and use the `key` parameter to retrieve the right document:

```
http://localhost:5984/<database>/_design/<designdoc>/_view/<viewname>?key=<pid2>
```

This should return all documents with `doc.pid === pid2`.